# Code broken for adding Download Link to Wordpress Default Audio Player

Tags: javascript, wordpress, audio

The codes to add download links automatically to audio embeds used to work, and now, suddenly i get errors saying Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function...

i am totally confused as to why

Sample link is https://mpmania.com/download-mp3/wizkid-ghetto-love-audio/

Ive used troubleshooting mode, deactivated all plugins, updated outdated ones, probably someone can help with rewriting these codes to work

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('audio').each(function( index ) {

        var source = $(this).find('source').attr('src');

        if ( source != '' ) {
            $(this).after('&lt;a href=&quot;' + source + '&quot; class=&quot;audio-download&quot; download&gt;Download (Alternative)&lt;/a&gt;');
        }

    });
});
```

I basically expect it to work as it used to

Comment: With Wordpress, jQuery runs in noConflict mode. Instead of using `$(document).ready(function()` use `jQuery(function($)` then within that function you can continue using `$` in your selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, your code should look like this:

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    $('audio').each(function(index) {
        var source = $(this).find('source').attr('src');
        if (source != '') {
            $(this).after('&lt;a href=&quot;' + source + '&quot; class=&quot;audio-download&quot; download&gt;Download (Alternative)&lt;/a&gt;');
        }
    });
});
```